# Received event.value is undefined on text input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateful component where I'm trying to render few stateless components (each with text input) using map.

The main problem is that when I'm putting the text into input I'm receiving `undefined` as an `event.target`. I guess that the problem is current context. I was trying to debug but I don't have more ideas how to resolve that issue.

Parent component:

```
handleUpdateInput = (name) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value }) // event.target = undefined
}

renderAdvancedOptions(fields) {
  return fields.map(field => {
    const { id, name } = field;

    return (
      <AdvancedOption
        key={id}
        name={name}
        inputValue={this.state[name]}
        handleUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Child component:

```
const AdvancedOption = ({ name, inputValue, handleUpdateInput }) => {
  return (
    <input
      name={name}
      onChange={() => handleUpdateInput(name)}
      value={inputValue}
      type="text"
    />
  );
};

export default AdvancedOption;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component's `handleUpdateInput`, you would need to include another parameter for the event to passed down.

```
handleUpdateInput = (name, event) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value }) // event.target = undefined
}
```

Otherwise the function does not know what `event` is.

Inside of the input, you will need to pass the event into the function,

```
onChange={(e) => handleUpdateInput(name, e)}
```

Take a look at the react documentation on how to create a controlled input:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you mate! It's working. I was so close with my previous solutions.